# OpenGL glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, opengl, opengl-compat

I'm new to OpenGL, and I'm going to make something like this. And the problem is, the loop seems like invoked only once, but I don't know why it becomes like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wcbh.png).

```c
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
int n = 32;
float angle = 0.0f;
float green = 0.0f;
float blue = 1.0f;
float color = 1.0/n;
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(0.0, 5.0, 0.0);
drawArrow();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    green = green + color;
    blue = blue - color;
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle+(360/n), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0, green, blue);
        drawArrow();
    glPopMatrix();
}

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: what is the expectation here?

Comment: You have shown a picture of the rotated arrow in different colors and I agree that it is a somewhat unexpected result for the shown code. But what do you expect? Maybe an arrow which changes color over time?

Comment: `angle+(360/n)` is the same each time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all the arrows are drawn with the same orientation.
What you want to do is to step forward the rotation of the arrows by an angle.

The angle for each arrow has to depend on the control variable of the loop (`i`). The angle between 2 arrows is `360.0/n` and the angle of an arrow is `360.0*i/n`:

<s>`glRotatef(angle+(360/n), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`</s>

```c
float partAngle = 360.0f * (float)i/(float)n;
glRotatef(angle + partAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

---

An other option would be to use the [`glPushMatrix` / `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml). Push the matrix after the rotation angle has been set, so the rotation grows up by `360.0f/n` in the loop:

```c
glPushMatrix();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    green = green + color;
    blue = blue - color;

    glRotatef(angle+(360.0f/n), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(0.0, green, blue);
        drawArrow();
    glPopMatrix();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the angle of an arrow is 360.0*i/n"? I do not see that - not within a pair of push/pop, which I expect to reset the effect of  `glRotatef()` in each loop iteration.

Comment: Please elaborate. I not get the "that" in your phrasing. Your explanation matches the picture, but not the code shown by OP.

Comment: Ah I see, so you guess that the picture shown by OP is the desired output, not the undesired one. Not an unplausible guess - but in my opinion still a guess. Thanks for explaining. I read however "I don't know why it becomes like <picture>." as "Why do I see this unexpected result?". Reading "How can I achieve the expected result?" into it seems a stretch to me. I wish OP would answer....

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    green += color;
    blue -= color;
    angle += 360 / n;

    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0, green, blue);
        drawArrow();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```